# XML Parsing having nested loops in the XML

Tags: xml-parsing

```
Please help me in this code 
I am suing a nested XML like 

    <agn:TXLife xmlns:agn="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2/Sales/v1" xmlns:ext="http://allstate.com/dmea/Sales/v1">
    <agn:OLifEExtension>
                <agn:OLifEExtension>
                  <ext:NetworkID>JBROWN</ext:NetworkID>
                </agn:OLifEExtension>
              </agn:OLifEExtension>
    </agn:TXLife>
```

I am not able to fetch the networdID "JBROWN". Please suggest me on this.

Comment: In which language you want to parse this XML?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    

                xDoc.Descendants(agn + "OLifEExtension").Descendants().Select(p => new
                {
                    NetworkID = p.Element(ext + "NetworkID").Value
    
                }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    String Result_OLifEExtension = p.NetworkID;
                    Logwrite(Result_OLifEExtension.ToString(), Dtime);
                });
    }

Comment: the problem is with the "OLifEExtension" if I remove this tab it's working fine

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap - I want in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you working with c# you can use the `XmlDocument` class
here is a code that can help you:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(path);

 XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;//Take the root node

 for (int i = 0; i < root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
 {
  var OLifEExtension = root.ChildNodes[i];
  var innerOLifEExtension = OLifEExtension.FirstChild;
  var NetworkID = innerOLifEExtension.FirstChild;
  Console.WriteLine("NetworkID: " + NetworkID.InnerText);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solutions:

But we are not able to enter into the for loop as it is showing the root.ChildNodes.Count = 0;

Comment: is the xml file looks like the xml you have posted?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agn:TXLife xmlns:agn="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2/Sales/v1" xmlns:ext="http://allstate.com/dmea/Sales/v1">
  <agn:TXLifeRequest id="ACORD_EPCSI_20161125" PrimaryObjectID="ACORD_EPCSI_20161125">
    <agn:TransRefGUID>ACORD_2.17_EPCSI_20161125</agn:TransRefGUID>
    <agn:TransType tc="A">A</agn:TransType>
    <agn:OLifE Version="2.20.00">
      <agn:SourceInfo>
        <agn:CreationDate>2016-11-25</agn:CreationDate>
      </agn:SourceInfo>

Comment: <agn:Party id="Party_00000999">
        <agn:PartyTypeCode tc="01">Employee</agn:PartyTypeCode>
        <agn:PartyKey>00000999</agn:PartyKey>
        <agn:FullName>JOHN A BROWN</agn:FullName>
        <agn:Person id="Person_00000999">
          <agn:FirstName>JOHN</agn:FirstName>
          <agn:MiddleName>A</agn:MiddleName>
          <agn:LastName>BROWN</agn:LastName>
          <agn:OLifEExtension>
            <agn:OLifEExtension>
              <ext:NetworkID>JBROWN</ext:NetworkID>
            </agn:OLifEExtension>
          </agn:OLifEExtension>
        </agn:Person>
</agn:Party>

Comment: this the original XML because of size constraint I am sending in the 2 comments

Comment: XmlNode root = doc.ChildNodes[1];

Comment: I am getting "ACORD_2.17_EPCSI_20161125" as  output, if I am using the whole XML

Comment: glad i helped you can click the it was useful button ;-)

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this site, I dint understand what you are suggesting me:P

Comment: where to click that it is usefull